# jQuery maps input name=id element to form.id property, Why?

Tags: jquery, html

I have html-forms which include a input tag with name=id
For some reason jQuery maps this field to the forms id property.
If you check the simple html below you will find

```
$('#f1')[0].id = [input element]#inputid
$('#f2')[0].id = "f2"
```

Does anybody know why, or is it a bug, and does anybody know where jquery maps the name=id element to the form?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Strange jQuery FORM.id behavior</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="f1" name="f1">
        <input id="inputid" name="id" value="ID">
    </form>

    <form id="f2" name="f2">
        <input name="key" value="KEY">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery-mobile will try to use this form.id string and fail if your form contains name=id inputs...

Tried most browsers, jquery verisons, same result.

**EDIT:**
Sorry - only checked jQuery, not jQuery-mobile for bugs, this was corrected Mar-12.
Not in 1.4.2 though, when patched with getAttribute('id') instead it works...

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/9ff610de479097c85ec7289e67fc656e5581d817

Comment: Don't give your input a name of `id`.

Comment: This isn't relative to jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in fact nothing to do with jQuery.

The problem is that, in the DOM, the elements in a form are accessible as properties of the form, with their `name` attribute as the key. This is documented [in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) (nb that it's not very reader-friendly). This value will overwrite the value of the `id` attribute in determining the property's value.

This is also true for `name` attributes which refer to other properties of the `form` element, like `submit`, `reset`, even `name`. (Go to [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YVTq/) and look at the error console after you click the link to see this problem in action.)

It is a bad idea to give your form elements `name` attributes that are the names of properties of the `form` element. Choose a different `name` instead.

Comment: +1 good explanation. I'm pretty sure this has been covered before on SO. Any idea if there's a canonical question/answer for this?

Comment: @j08691 I'm sure it has too. I'm fairly sure I've written such an answer! But I did look and I couldn't find anything canonical-looking.

Comment: The problem was jquery-mobile, the bug is apparently now corrected. Didn't know that the elements were mapped to the form properties by HTML. Note that if an element have both id and name attributes it is mapped to the form.[name] property, if it only have id, it is mapped to the form.[id] property

Comment: @jorese Well the problem is fundamental to naming your HTML elements. But yes, what you say does indeed show why you have to be careful with your element names/ids.